# Was Veigar's Event Horizon hotfixed?

Tags: league-of-legends

In patch V1.0.0.141 released on June 17, 2012, Riot [fixed Veigar's stun](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.141): it used to only stun every 0.25 sec so that if a champion dashed through it, it had a chance to not stun the champion. The fix was to ensure that a champion dashing through Event Horizon is stunned in place.

But today, an enemy Riven, Graves and Ahri were all jumping in and out of my stun without getting stunned! So did they fixed Event Horizon or not?

Comment: Hey Samae3l, Welcome to Arqade! Thanks for posting a question too! To improve your question, I would edit the wording to avoid asking about a current event. Because here on Arqade, we're really trying to build a resource for future users as well as answer everyone's questions; so Arqade is a bit different from a forum. For example, you could ask, "Can champions dash or flash through Veigar's Event Horizon?" A good answer will also address whether the mechanic changed in any patches.

Comment: The stun only stuns them once per cast, not once per crossing of your circle line. Keep that in mind.

Comment: @Ender Actually according to the [abilities details on Event Horizon](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Veigar_the_Tiny_Master_of_Evil/Ability_Details), "Champions can be stunned multiple times if they walk through two different walls of the ability."

Answer (score 2):

This is a change on the public test realm.  It will be part of the Eve/Twitch remake patch. As of the date of this post, that patch has not been deployed on the live servers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [Zyra Patch Notes](http://summonermatch.com/patchnotes.php)

> I dont see anything about Veigar but as mentioned this is supposed to be a hotfix and most likely wont be added until the release of the new patch in full detail. I have tested the gate on PBE (which you can also sign up for and play on) and it works with dash. The problem should be fixed in the next patch.
>
> In my opinion, your best bet when playing Veigar is to cast your gate on the edge so is directly on your intended target and use that instant stun rather than relying on them trying to run out.
>
> Other than this you'll just have to pray to the blind draft gods that they dont pick champions with dash mechanics when you pick Veigar.
>
> Hope this helps :)